# Is first level cache enabled in my Castle ActiveRecord based application?

Tags: nhibernate, caching, castle-activerecord, first-level-cache

I have a simple level ASP.NET web application based on Castle ActiveRecord. How can I determine if first level cache is enabled within it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First level cache can never be disabled. It's always on.

Comment: But I have heard somewhere that first level cache is by default enabled. Does this sentence means that it can be disabled?

Comment: I said explicitly __can never be disabled__

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not thinking of the [Second Level Cache?](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/02/09/quickly-setting-up-and-using-nhibernate-s-second-level-cache.aspx)

The first level cache is essentially an [identity map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) and as such, is always enabled.

Comment: I mean exactly first level cache.